# Data insertion error while parsing Json array in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, json

Hi am getting an **offset error** with this code while parsing the data:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\path on line 15
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\path on line 16
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\path on line 18
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\path on line 19
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\path on line 20
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\path on line 21
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\path on line 22
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\path on line 23
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\path on line 26
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\path on line 15
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\path on line 16
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\path on line 18
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\path on line 19
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\path on line 20
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\path on line 21
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\path on line 22
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\path on line 23
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\path on line 26

**Code**

```
<?php
  include('config.php');
    // read json file
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET"){
    $filename = 'chemist.json';
    $json_data = file_get_contents($filename);   
    // $json_data=$_POST['QUESTION'];
    //convert json object to php associative array
    $data = json_decode($json_data,true);
    print_r($data);

if (is_array($data) || is_object($data))
{
    for($j=0;$j<sizeof($data);$j++){
        $jsonData[$j] = $data[$j]['DATA'];
        $jsonPob[$j] = $data[$j]['POB'];

        $name = $data[$j]['DATA']['CHEMIST_NAME'];
        $mobile = $data[$j]['DATA']['CHEMIST_MOBILE'];
        $products = $data[$j]['DATA']['STOCKIEST_NAME'];
        $prd = $data[$j]['DATA']['PRODUCT_CODE'];
        $createdby = $data[$j]['DATA']['CREATEDBY'];
        $createdon = $data[$j]['DATA']['CREATEDON'];


        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($data[$j]['POB']);$i++)
        {

            $pob[$i] = $data[$j]['POB'][$i]['POB_NAME'];
            $pobqty[$i] = $data[$j]['POB'][$i]['POB_QTY'];

            $pob=$pob[$i];
            $pobqty=$pobqty[$i];
            // echo $pob[$i]." <--> ".$pobqty[$i]."<br/>";
            $sql="INSERT INTO CHEMISTDEATILS(CHEMIST_NAME,CHEMIST_MOBILE,STOCKIEST_NAME,PRODUCT_CODE,POB_NAME,POB_QTY,CREATEDBY,CREATEDON)
        VALUES ('$name', '$mobile', '$stock', '$prd', '$pob[$i]', '$pobqty[$i]','$createdby', '$createdon');";
            $qur = mysql_query($sql);
        if($qur){
        $json = array("status" => 1, "msg" => "Done User added!");
        }else{
        $json = array("status" => 2, "msg" => "Already Submitted");
    }

        }
        // echo "<br/>-----------<br/>";


    }


}

}else{
    $json = array("status" => 0, "msg" => "Request method not accepted");
}


@mysql_close($conn);

/* Output header */
// header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);    
    //close connection
 ?>
```

**Sample Json data**

```
{
    "DATA": {
        "PRODUCT_CODE": "H5414110104,H5414110105,H5414110201,",
        "CHEMIST_NAME": "Bhu",
        "CHEMIST_MOBILE": "8985188306",
        "STOCKIEST_POB_NAME": "Chkj",
        "CREATEDON": "2017-09-16 08:53:10",
        "CREATEDBY": 10643
    },
    "POB": [{
        "POB_NAME": "TASTE GOOD",
        "POB_QTY": 10
    }, {
        "POB_NAME": "GLUCOWISE",
        "POB_QTY": 10
    }, {
        "POB_NAME": "ISTAPHASE",
        "POB_QTY": 10
    }, {
        "POB_NAME": "PRIME",
        "POB_QTY": 10
    }, {
        "POB_NAME": "JIOTAN",
        "POB_QTY": 10
    }, {
        "POB_NAME": "ROST",
        "POB_QTY": 10
    }, {
        "POB_NAME": "EXTEL",
        "POB_QTY": 10
    }]
}
```

Comment: here `$data[$j]['DATA']` you don't need the index `$j`. should be `$data['DATA']`. same for `POB`.

Comment: yes the values are inserting but i have only 7 rows but 14 row are inserting please look into this @Jeff

Comment: of course you then also don't need the first `for ($j=0..)` loop